# getchars() sequence off by 1byte

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I set up a test example of `getchars()` call and the returns the bytes are off sequence by 1.

```
byte [] readBufA = new byte [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; // Test array
```

I then run the getchar and the result is off by 1.

```
String strIncom = new String(readBufA, 0, 7); // create string from bytes array
String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1); // create string from bytes array

sb.append(strIncom); // append string
int counter = sb.length(); // Get length of string
if (counter == 7){

getChars(0,7,readBufA,0);


Log.d(TAG, "Data " + sb + "  Size  " + (char)readBuf[0] + " " + (char)readBuf[1] +
" " + (char)readBuf[2] + " " + (char)readBuf[3] + " " +(char)readBuf[4] + 
" " + (char)readBuf[5] + " " + (char)readBuf[6] +" " + (char)readBuf[7]+ " " + counter); // receive massage
```

The `log.d` returns (2,3,4,5,6,7,-,-,7) counter is correct but dont see the correct return

Comment: Are `readBufA` and `readBuf` identical? You defined `readBufA` in the question. But, `Log.i(...)` reads `readBuf`.

Comment: Typo, readBuf and readBufA are identical

Comment: Refer to [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Also, `(char)readBuf[7]` would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since `readBuf's` size is 7. Try using `byte [] readBufA = new byte [] {49,50,51,52,53,34,55};`. The output would be `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`.

Comment: I performed the test to resolve the data cross over from string to byte[]. The suggestion did resolve the sequence problem but I am back to the same issue when I run the original code (with test removed) to append data. Each byte received gets sb.append(strIncom)  stored in the string until a total of 7 are received. then converted back to bytes[] The result of log.d (2,3,4,5,6,7,X,7)